# How to update incorrect state of class in react?

Tags: reactjs

In the code below, when I change text in the input, it updates the value of input incorrectly, but when I press enter, data updates in the two `ul` tags. Any idea what I've done wrong?

```
<script type="text/jsx">  
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var todoList = React.createClass({
  render : function(){
      var createItem = function(itemText , idx){
        return <li key={idx+itemText} >{itemText}</li>
      };
      return <ul>{this.props.itemlist.map(createItem)}</ul>
  }
});

var todoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
      return {items: [], text: ''};
  },
  handleChange:function(name ,e){
    this.state.text = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ name : e.target.value });
  },
  handleKeyDown : function(e , idx){
    if( e.keyCode == 13 ){
      var nextItems = this.state.items.concat([this.state.text]);
      this.setState({ items : nextItems , text : '' });
    }
  },
  render :function(){
    var results = this.props.items;
    return (
      <div>
        {results.map(function(idx ,item){              
          this.state.items[idx] = item;
          return (
            <div key={'outer'+idx}>
              <todoList itemlist={this.state.items} /> 
              <input key={idx} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, item)} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  />
            </div>
          );                
        } , this)}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<todoApp items={['item1','item2']} />, document.getElementById('example') );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had 'name' as the key, but it should be 'text'.

```
 handleChange:function(name ,e){
    this.state.text = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ text : e.target.value });
  },
```

You also need to pass the value to the input:

```
<input key={idx} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, item)} 
       onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} 
       value={this.state.text} />
```

Comment: thanks for answer but it's not right with mine idea, ex facebook when typing comment on one post and press enter then is's add to list's comments bellow of post.

Comment: I don't understand what you want it to do.